# How to get Anti-Malware events from Trend Micro Cloud One API

Tags: trend, workload, antimalware

Does anybody know how to get a list of Anti-Malware events from the Trend Micro Cloud one Endpoint and Workload Security API?

I can see the events on the UI, but didn't find anything in the API docs about it.

[image: Screenshot of what I'm trying to get]

Comment: Please share more details. How is this problem related to programming?